# ECMAScript 6 support for node.js and its different packages like express body_parser natively

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to migrate old nodejs (version 6.x) rest service project to latest nodejs (version 9.6.1) rest service project and want to follow ECMAScript 6 specification without any transplier.

The current project uses express, body-parser, moment, multer, cors, ethereumjs-tx, secp256k1, requirejs and some other nodejs modules, so my question is, does all these different modules as well as nodejs support ECMAScript 6 specification natively.

In internet I saw lots of solutions using bable transplier but I do not want to follow that approach.

Again I found https://github.com/mench/express-restful-es6 a ECMAScript 6 implementation of express but again it does not work. It failed on default import and use of decoration with @.

So is the ECMAScript 6 support for node.js and it modules are already implemented or should I wait for some time.

## EDIT

I agree the decorator patter support is not in ECMAScript 6, but import and export are also not working, I tried to run the following code ...

```
import express from 'express'
import restful from 'express-restful-es6'

var server = express()

console.log(restful)
restful.configure(server,{
    dirname: '/projectlocation' + '/resources'
})

server.listen(9000)
console.log("Listening on port 9000 .....")
```

but got following error...

```
> ethereum-rest-api@1.0.0 start /projectlocation/ethereum-rest-api
> /nodelocation/bin/node --experimental-modules index.mjs

(node:31753) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
{ Rest: [Function: Rest],
  middleware: [Function: middleware],
  default: Restful {} }
TypeError: restful.configure is not a function
    at file:///projectlocation/index.mjs:7:9
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/loader/ModuleJob.js:102:14)
    at <anonymous>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 start: `/nodelocation/bin/node --experimental-modules index.mjs`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Again @lorefnon if a module does not support ECMAScript 6 style import/export will I be able to import it in my code, for example if I try to work with lastest expression.js can I import it with ECMAScript 6 syntax without any transplier.

Comment: It appears that module is using [decorators](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-decorators-what-they-are/).  That is not ES6 functionality.  I believe that is proposed future functionality (beyond ES6) and you will either need an environment that supports decorators or you will need to transpile it.

Comment: Can you show what code you're trying to use with this library?

Comment: The current 8.x versions of node.js do support ES6 quite well and even support many ES7 features.  You don't have to wait for ES6 support.  Decorators, on the other hand, are not ES6 features.

Comment: @jfriend00 2 Please check my updated post I added some code and the error message in it.

Comment: If you have problems with import and export, why did you accept an answer that does not address that issue at all?  Or, is the problem not actually caused by import/export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6 is fully backward compatible. So, libraries and SDKs don't have to do anything additional to be ES6 compliant.

Of course, they may (or may not) choose to use ES-Next features, but it is common practice that any libraries using features not supported in the versions of the node they target, transpile their source as a part of their publishing process so consumers don't have to bother with transpiling of libraries.

If you ensure that your application uses the ES6 features supported by node you don't have to use a transpiler.

> Again I found https://github.com/mench/express-restful-es6 a ECMAScript 6 implementation of express but again it does not work. It failed on default import and use of decoration with @.

Their examples use the decorator syntax currently not supported by Node.

However if you want to avoid transpilation you can use the exposed functions as plain functions instead of decorators:

```
@Rest('/api')
class ApiResource {
    use(){
        //authorize
        console.info("authorize");
        this.next();
    }

}
```

is basically syntax sugar for:

```
class ApiResource_ {
    use(){
        //authorize
        console.info("authorize");
        this.next();
    }
}

const ApiResource = Rest('/api')(ApiResource_)
```

Comment: If you look at the actual library mentioned in the question, it is using decorators which is not something that is part of ES6.  So, this question isn't actually about ES6 features - it's about a feature beyond ES6.

Comment: That is not exactly true. Their **examples** do use decorators, but their published code does not. So can use the library without transpilation, if application code does not use decorators and uses them as function calls instead.